# getting folder hierarchy with bash or php

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm working with a linux machine that I'm not familiar with, so I'd like to get a txt print out of its folder structure. I remember having written a script that does something similar in php, but can't find it. I'm looking for any of the following that might help me with this task:

- a bash script
- an existing linux command line
- a php script

Comment: Did you try the `find` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 find . -type d > dirstructure.txt
```

However, on a typcial linux box, I'd rather not run this from the directory root. If you do and get a couple of permission errors, you could send the errors to `/dev/null`

```
 find . -type d > dirstructure.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Adding -maxdepth # might also be useful if you don't want to go too deep in the directory structure. To only display two levels it would be: `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d`

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
class Crawl_directory
{
    public $exclude = array();
    public $paths = array();
    public $tree = FALSE;
    public $tree_str = FALSE;
    public function __construct($path, $exclude = array())
{
        if ( !$path || !is_dir($path) )
            return FALSE;
        $this->exclude = array_merge(array(), $exclude);
        $this->tree = $this->crawl($path);
        $this->tree_str = $this->create_tree($this->tree);
}
    public function crawl($path)
    {
        $arr = array();
        $items = scandir($path);
        $this->paths[] = $path;
        foreach ( $items as $k => $v ) {
            if ( !in_array($v, $this->exclude) && $v != '.' && $v != '..' ) {
                if ( is_dir($path.'/'.$v) ) {
                    $arr[$v] = $this->crawl($path.'/'.$v);
                } else {
                    $arr[$v] = '';
                }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    function create_tree($arr)
    {
        $out = '<ul>'."\n";
        foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
            $out .= '<li class="'.((is_array($v)) ? 'folder' : 'file').'">'.$k.'</li>'."\n";
            if ( is_array($v) ) {
                $out .= $this->create_tree($v);
            }
        }
        $out .= '</ul>'."\n";
        return $out;    
    }
    function get_tree()
    {
        return $this->tree; 
        }
    function print_tree()
    {
        echo $this->tree_str;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

taken from http://www.centerkey.com/tree/